# Constructor with abstract class - won't accept specific

Tags: java

I have an abstract class Animal with extended classes of Horse and Pig. I also have a Farm class and a constructor in that class which I want to use to populate a list of what Animals are in the Farm. But the compiler is showing errors.

I will list the Farm class as I think this will illustrate the problem without needing to list the whole thing:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Farm {
    public ArrayList<Animal> farmlist;
    { 
        System.out.println("Initializing the farmlist...");
        farmlist = new ArrayList<>();
        farmlist.add(new Horse()); // There will always be a Horse in the farm.
    }

    public Farm() {
        System.out.println("Blank constructor called..");

    }

    public Farm(Animal animal, int n) {
        System.out.println("Multiple animal constructor called...");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            farmlist.add(new animal());
        }
    }
}
```

The last line of code gives a compiler error, it does not seem to allow me to pass in type Pig, for example, if I wanted to. The idea is that it will add multiple animals of whatever type I pass in to the farmlist. I cannot understand why it will not let me do this or what way I need to "phrase" what I am trying to do.

Comment: Is the class name Animal or animal? Java is case sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The idea is that it will add multiple animals of whatever type I pass in to the farmlist.

In that case you need to pass in the *type* of an `Animal` - not a reference to an *instance* of an `Animal`, which is what you're doing at the moment. I suspect you actually want something like:

```
public Farm(Class<? extends Animal> animalType, int n)
       throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    System.out.println("Multiple animal constructor called...");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        farmlist.add(animalType.newInstance());
    }
}
```

That will try to call an accessible parameterless constructor on whatever type you pass in, `n` times. You'd call it like this:

```
Farm farm = new Farm(Pig.class, 10);
```

Another option (most suitable for Java 8+) would be to pass in a *function* which created a new animal. For example:

```
public Farm(Supplier<? extends Animal> supplier, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        farmlist.add(supplier.get());
    }
}
```

then call it with:

```
Farm farm = new Farm(() -> new Pig(), 10);
```

Note that if you use kocko's answer with your original signature, you don't end up with multiple independent animal objects - you end up with your list containing several references to the *same* animal object. It's very important to understand how objects and references work in Java - and it's probably something best learned from a good book or tutorial.

Comment: Excellent - that clears it up. If I had passed an Object in then I would be creating multiple references to the same object, which is silly. Thanks Jon :)